# How to save data in current uid in Firebase

Tags: swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I can't save new data ("messages") to current user.

my code for push user info to Firebase

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference! = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

self.ref.child("Users").child("UserID").childByAutoId().setValue(["Name": userName, "Email": userEmail])
```

code for push messages to Firebase

```
var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
messageRef.child("Users").child("UserID").child(self.uid!).child("Messages").childByAutoId().setValue(["Sender Name": Profile.sharedProfile.Name!,"Date": self.currentDate(),"Time": self.currentTime(), "Text": self.text.text!])
```

[It's what i see in Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx46V.png)

but i want's like this [messages need save in current user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W5Tu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first block of code is incorrect. If you want to put your `Messages` under existed `User`, you should use `child(self.uid!)` instead of `childByAutoId()`, because the second method generates new instance in firebase DB. So your code should looks something like:

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference! = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
self.ref.child("Users").child("UserID").child(self.uid!).setValue(["Name": userName, "Email": userEmail])
```